# Failure reported in Quartz 2.2.2 scheduler

Tags: quartz-scheduler, scheduler, quartz

I am getting below error 
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (QRTZ_FIRED_TRIGGER_PK) violated

I am not sure why this would fail as out of these two (SCHED_NAME,ENTRY_ID) pkey, Sched_name is always same for all jobs and ENTRY_ID is generated by Quartz itself.

Can anyone please help me find how this ENTRY_ID is created and in which scenario this can cause PK failure.

There are multiple Quartz JOBS scheduled on same interval in my application.

Answer (score 0):

The ENTRY_ID is determined by the `instanceId` of your node with an appended counter. (e.g. "mynode1557833519480")

This collision can happen when you have two nodes with the same instanceId in your cluster.

Make sure the instanceIds are unique. From Quartz-documentation:

> **org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId**
>
> Can be any string, but must be unique for all schedulers working as if they are the same ‘logical’ Scheduler within a cluster. You may use the value “AUTO” as the instanceId if you wish the Id to be generated for you

(The counter is initialized with the current time, so if the system clock was turned back at some point, this could also happen)

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the details.
For me the entryID is coming as SchedulerFactory1557622096430 so I believe SchedulerFactory is the ID and yes I have multiple nodes here in this environment. Can you please suggest what can be done to sort this out.